# Dar color a partes del texto de un textBox

Tags: c#, color, textbox

tengo este código:

```
string Clei=string.Empty;

Clei = "Se confecciona boleta # "+  txtNumeroBoleta.Text + ", del " + a + " al " + b + " (" + dias + " días), firmada por el usuario: " + usuario + " código. " + codigoUsuario + ".";

txtNota.Text=Clei;
```

El asunto es el siguiente, requiero dar un color diferente a los datos que vienen de las variables y de los demás txt que serán mostrados en el txtNota.

Espero un resultado como el siguiente:

> Se confecciona boleta # **121212**, del **02/07/2018** al **12/07/2018** (**10** días), firmada por el usuario: **Jan Carlos Vargas**  código. **601230123**.

**NOTA**:Negritas en color distinto

Comment: Creo que un textbox no puedes hacer eso, creo que necesitas un richtextbox

Comment: Como lo hago en un richtextbox

Comment: Gracias. Ya realice la búsqueda con un richtextbox y encontré resultados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando `TextBox` imposible, pero es algo sencillo de hacer usando [RichTextBox](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/richtextbox-overview) con el siguiente método extendido

```
public static class RichTextBoxExtensions
{
    public static void AppendText(this RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
    {
        box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
        box.SelectionLength = 0;    
        box.SelectionColor = color;
        box.AppendText(text);
        box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;
    }
}
```

---

Luego, simplemente haces uso de esta extensión de la siguiente manera

```
//Color rojo
richTextBox1.AppendText("Texto en color rojo!", Color.Red);
//Color negro
richTextBox1.AppendText("Texto en color negro!");
//Color verde
richTextBox1.AppendText("Texto en color rojo!", Color.Green);
```

El extension method, lo tome de la [respuesta de Nathan Baulch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1926822/5213794) en [StackOverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com)